# vue session storages retrieving value from another page

Tags: vue.js

i store session values at login.html

```
axios.post(this.url,data)
     .then( function (response ) {
         if(response.data.success){
             window.location.href = "http://localhost/dairyweb/index.html"
             sessionStorage.setItem('email',this.email)

         }else {
             alert(response.data.message)
         }
     }.bind(this)).catch(function (error) {
    // bind to initialize an object
 })
```

On the index.html , I want to retrieve the value and using this but not working

```
computed: {
            userType (){
                return sessionStorage.getItem('email')
            }
        }
```

here is how am retrieving

```
{{userType}}
```

This not working on the next page.  no erros just silent

Comment: check you browser session storage and see if the email is successfully stored

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at the possibility of using postmessages. Then fire it when *storage changes occur.

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage

You could also exchange storage data from tab to tab.

http://blog.guya.net/2015/06/12/sharing-sessionstorage-between-tabs-for-secure-multi-tab-authentication/

I'd post this as a comment as it's not a full answer, but I don't have enough points, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

sessionStorage within Vue isn't explicitly bound to the window where it's being stored which is why it's not correctly being saved.

You'll need to use the `window` object: 
`window.sessionStorage.setItem('email',this.email)` alongside `return window.sessionStorage.getItem('email')`

Alternatively you could look to use an external package which binds your local storage to the Vue object so you can call `this.$ls.set()` from `this`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-local-storage